# Fixing undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was working on the photos controller, and now all of a sudden certain users are not able to view their profile, and a `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` error shows.

I have been looking around and I'm not sure what I did to cause this. I know it reads `undefined method state`, but the users all have a zip code that belongs to a state. And all of the profiles were working. I first noticed this because my personal profile showed the error.

User Model:

```
  belongs_to :location, :foreign_key => :zip_code, :primary_key => :zip_code

  def similar
    arr = User.where(:gender => self.gender).where.not(:id => self.id)
    arr.select{|c| c.location.state == self.location.state }
  end

  def location

      if Location.by_zip_code(self.zip_code.to_s).any?
          return Location.by_zip_code(self.zip_code.to_s).first
      else
          return nil
      end
  end
```

Users Controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
    @similar_users = @user.similar.shuffle.first(8)
      end
```

Comment: The error message is citing your `user.rb` model, but you haven't shown any of that code. What does line 75 in your `app/models/user.rb` file look like? And perhaps some context around it?

Comment: Looks like an issue in the `similar` method in your `User` model.

Comment: @lurker User model has been added for that line. What's throwing me off is I haven't touch that model in over two months and this is the first time it has thrown an error.

Comment: The error is inside of your user model code for the similar method. You're calling the method state on a nil object. You should either paste your user model code or check out the variables before you call state.

Comment: In that context, the error message is telling you that either `self.location` or `c.location` is `nil`. Without more of the pertinent code, it's hard to tell why. Just because each user has a zip code doesn't automatically define the relation for `location` for each user. Check your data and check that you've defined the relation between `user` and `location` correctly in the `User` and `Location` models.

Comment: Are you sure that you should be converting zip codes to a string (with `to_s` before looking for them in `Location`? How are zip codes defined in your schema for `users` and `locations`? I see also that you're overriding the default association method that Rails already provides you (`location`). It would probably be better practice to use a different name so as not to obscure the original in case you need it.

Comment: @lurker schema has been added.

Comment: It's pretty clear that `Location.by_zip_code(self.zip_code.to_s).any?` is turning up `false`. So you need to examine the value of `self.zip_code.to_s` and your location table contents to make sure they're matchable. As I mentioned, I think it's a bad idea to override the Rails `belongs_to` relation this way. It defeats the purpose of having the relation defined with the `belongs_to`. The purpose of it is to fetch the location of the user by the `location_id` in the user table, not find it by zip code. If you want to find it by zip code, you don't need the relation.

Comment: @lurker I will fix the `belongs_to`. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your logs you can see that you're calling the method state on something thats nil.

Jul 28 19:14:21 domain app/web.1:  NoMethodError (undefined method `state' for nil:NilClass): 
Jul 28 19:14:21 domain app/web.1:    app/models/user.rb:75:in`block in similar' 
Jul 28 19:14:21 domain app/web.1:    app/models/user.rb:75:in `similar'

In your edited answer you can see the culprit. You return nil in this else statement.

```
  def location
      if Location.by_zip_code(self.zip_code.to_s).any?
          # you can return all here if you want more than one
          # for testing just returning the first one
          return Location.by_zip_code(self.zip_code.to_s).first
      else
          return nil
      end
  end
```

But you don't check for nil here (c.location.state)

```
def similar
    arr = User.where(:gender => self.gender).where.not(:id => self.id)
    arr.select{|c| c.location.state == self.location.state }
end
```

Something like what I have below might do the trick

```
def similar
    arr = User.where(:gender => self.gender).where.not(:id => self.id)
    arr.select{ |c|
        if !c.location.nil? 
            return c.location.state == self.location.state
        else
            return false
        end
    }
end
```

For the other part of the problem, you could potentially have errors in your Location model. Without seeing that code I can't help you but the above will help your code to fail gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for looking to assist. I think the biggest problem is my pride because I believe the error is incorrect lol. I can't possibly see that I setup the Location wrong. ```has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  scope :by_zip_code, ->(zip_code) { where('zip_code = ?', zip_code) }```. I will have it figured out shortly, as I know it'll be the smallest, silliest mistake.

Comment: Hahaha it happens to the best of us.